# Run Python Program on Site

Tags: python

this is a question that I don't know where to search for an answer. I have a Python program that has too many calculations, for example, consider the DFS algorithm with branch factor equals 62 and depth equal to 20. If I run this program on my pc I would take ages to be completed. But is there any website that gives me resources to do this job? Like I put my code in it and run it then two days later check the results.
 
I'm aware that maybe this question flagged as spam or anything like that, but thanks for your help anyway!
**UPDATE**
I investigate further on this little question. What I really want is a *Cloud Computing* but for free!!

Comment: Maybe try Amazon AWS?

Comment: Hi @Andrew, As long as I'm in the country that is not listed in Amazon AWS system, I cannot use this service.

Comment: you can use something like heroku, or any other cloud service with subscription which is free for some time, or maybe repl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that cloud computing could help you as it might take ages in cloud as well. Cloud computing should be used when your code can be efficiently parallelised into problems with reasonable complexity. You can parallelise DFS (say, based on the choice of the first branch) but you still left with the problem of almost the same size. You should consider optimising/approximating your calculations to be runnable with restricted resources.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on what to do, I created another question on this problem, please check it out. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745336/find-all-possible-fixed-size-string-python)