# Find All Possible Fixed Size String Python

Tags: python

**Problem:**
I want to generate all possible combination from 36 characters that consist of alphabet and numbers in a fixed length string. Assume that the term "fixed length" is the upper bound for my string length. 
Some of these combinations are listed below:

```
a
b
c
.
.
z
0
1
.
.
9
.
.
.
aaaaaa
aaaaab
.
.
99999999999999999998
99999999999999999999 // end of the list
```

I don't want to store them in memory or disk because I calculate something on them and if they don't meet the goal result, well, I don't need it anymore.

 **Approaches:** 
1. For the first try, I choose recursion to create strings. But it's so awful in using memory. 
2. For the second try, I use DFS algorithm because it's nearly optimal in using memory as it's around *O(bm)*. But as time view, it's very time-consuming.
Is there any other way to do this more optimized?

 **UPDATE** 
Here is possible outputs for length 2 and 3 character:

```
a
b
c
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`.

Comment: And I don't know why I got negative points. If there is a problem with my explanation or my question, please tell me, not just hit the "not useful" arrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this. It returns a generator of sequences of fixed length.

As you order your strings first by length and then lexicographically, you may use something like this

```
import itertools

for l in range(1, 5):
    for seq in itertools.product("abc", repeat=l):
        print("".join(seq))
```

Comment: This tool does not work as I expected, here are results for the above code:
`a
b
c
aa
ab
ac
bb
bc
cc
aaa
aab
aac
abb
abc
acc
bbb
bbc
bcc
ccc
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aabb
aabc
aacc
abbb
abbc
abcc
accc
bbbb
bbbc
bbcc
bccc
cccc`
It's missing "ba" or "aaba"

Comment: Fixed, as the order matters we need to use `itertools.product`.

Comment: Thank You for your help, it works perfectly and produces what I need. By the way, is there any possibility to reduce execution time? Cause as I mentioned in the question I have to check some circumstances to whether accept the output or not. What can I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion, regardless of algorithm, might be the simplest way to go. Unfortunately you are right, it could use a lot of memory opening up each frame as it recurs down. You might even hit the recursion limit.

I would check out Continuation Passing Style. It's an optimization that allows for fewer frames to be used when doing large recursive work like this. It would not hit the recursion limit and probably speed things up. I'm pretty sure that Python supports this optimization. It's an advanced topic, so it might take some time to make work.

http://baruchel.github.io/blog/python/2015/07/10/continuation-passing-style-in-python/

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out.